# Redirecting output from an Oracle console application in a named pipe

Tags: command-line, bash, oracle, pipe

I'm currently developing a plugin to compile Oracle code in my text editor. The folks that developed SQL Developer recently added a command line version `sqlcl`. The problem is, this a Java application - and firing this up (`jvm`) each time I need to do a compilation can be expensive - with some reports of it taking ~20 seconds.

One suggestion I've seen was to use a named pipe, which if I do so manually, appears to work well.

Terminal 1:

```
mkfifo sqlconsole
tail -f sqlconsole | /opt/sqlcl/bin/sql /nolog
```

Terminal 2:

```
echo "conn hr/hr@example.com/xe" > sqlconsole
```

And the statements are run successfully.

The issue with this though, is that in terminal 2, I'm not getting any of the output from terminal 1 (which I want).

[image]

..

I found this [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash) about reading output from a named pipe, however even with that, the output from `sqlcl` is not re-directed (and, as writing this up, seems to have broken input)

```
#!/bin/bash
#consolereader.sh
trap "rm -f sqlconsole" EXIT

if [[ ! -p sqlconsole ]]; then
    echo "pipe does not exist" >&2
    exit 1
fi

while true
do
    if read line < sqlconsole; then
        if [[ "$line" == 'quit' ]]; then
            break
        fi
        echo $line
    fi
done
```

Terminal 1:

```
mkfifo sqlconsole
tail -f sqlconsole | /opt/sqlcl/bin/sql /nolog
```

Terminal 2:

```
./consolereader.sh &
echo "conn hr/hr@example.com/xe" > sqlconsole
```

[image]

Is there a better approach I can take - such that I can leave `sqlcl` running in the background, and still get the output in the session I send the commands from?

..

Edit: Trying Germar's solution:

setUpPipes.sh (terminal 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f sqlconsole
rm -f sqlconsole_out
mkfifo sqlconsole
mkfifo sqlconsole_out
tail -f sqlconsole | /opt/sqlcl/bin/sql /nolog | tee -a sqlconsole_out
```

compileOracle.sh (terminal 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "begin.."
tail -f /home/trent/pipedemo/sqlconsole_out &
echo "about to run connection"
echo "conn hr/hr@example.com/xe" > /home/trent/pipedemo/sqlconsole
echo "select * from dual" > /home/trent/pipedemo/sqlconsole
echo "disconnect" > /home/trent/pipedemo/sqlconsole
echo "finished"
exit 0
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understood your problem but what about `echo "conn hr/hr@example.com/xe" | tee -a sqlconsole`? `tee` reads from standard input and write to standard output and files

Comment: Oh, I really misunderstood your question. Sorry. Sounds like you need to open a second fifo `sqlcl_out`, pipe all output from Terminal 1 into that `tail -f sqlconsole | /opt/sqlcl/ /nolog | tee -a sqlcl_out` and read it in Terminal 2 with `tail -f sqlcl_out &`

Comment: Regarding your edit: maybe `sqlcl` doesn't write to stdout but stderr!? Try again with `tail -f sqlconsole | /opt/sqlcl/bin/sql /nolog 3>&1 1>&3 2>&3 | tee -a sqlconsole_out`

Comment: Thanks for persisting. Yeah, still nothing from the `SQL>` Console comes through.

Comment: Does it work with `tail -f sqlconsole | /opt/sqlcl/bin/sql /nolog 2>&1 > sqlconsole_out`? That won't show anything on Terminal 1 for sure...

Comment: When I run it per scripts in above post (with the change in the above comment), the output goes neither here nor there (aside from the program and copyright notice). 

If I send commands interactively in the terminal (outside the script), it's only after I send `exit` to the SQL console does all the output appear  (neither case ideal).

Comment: Just doing more testing, if I do multiple `connects` and `disconnects`, after the `exit` statement, the output that comes through is a bit patchy. And yeah, `exit` obviously kills the process which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach you could take is to make use of the `SPOOL` command in your SQL interpreter.

So, start your named pipe as you were already doing so:

```
mkfifo sqlconsole
tail -f sqlconsole | /opt/sqlcl/bin/sql /nolog
```

Next, make your SQL script, but this time enabling `serveroutput` and also spooling to a specified file. In this example, I will just do it to `out.txt`.

```
conn hr/hr@example.com/xe
SPOOL out.txt    
select * from dual;

set serveroutput on

exec dbms_output.put_line('PROCESS_FINISHED');

SPOOL OFF
disconnect
```

Here, I've also opted to print a string to the spooled file - `PROCESS_FINISHED` - as a way to flag when the script has finished, since the SQL script and bash script will be running side by side, with the bash script likely to complete before the script has finished.

With that, then I can make a bash script (`atomRunner.sh`) to send it to the named pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash
> out.txt
cat connect.sql > sqlconsole
MAX_TIME=10
scriptStart=$(date -u +"%s")
secondsSince=0

while true; do

    if [[ "${secondsSince}" -ge "${MAX_TIME}" ]] || grep -q "PROCESS_FINISHED" out.txt; then
        break
    fi
    nowDate=$(date -u +"%s")
    secondsSince=$((nowDate-scriptStart))
    sleep 0.1
done

cat out.txt

if [[ "${secondsSince}" -ge "${MAX_TIME}" ]]; then
    echo "Script took longer than expected to complete" >&2
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Then running:

```
$ ./atomRunner.sh 

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> select * from dual;

D
-
X
SQL> exec dbms_output.put_line('PROCESS_FINISHED')
PROCESS_FINISHED

SQL> SPOOL OFF
```